# How can i use position:absolute in gmail

Tags: css, position, gmail, html, absolute

I try to use **position:absolute** in gmail, but doesn't is possible.

The code I try to use: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/JGDwb/2/)

```
div#teste {position: absolute; margin-left: 68.2% ! important; margin-top: 28.4% ! important;}
```

Someone help me?

I thank you,
Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid but as far as I know absolute positioning is not allowed in Gmail. You have to use tables for all your positioning. Am struggling with this myself at the moment